# Scatter plot linear trend does not match data analysis toolpak

Tags: excel-formula

When I create a scatterplot of my data, and go to Add Trendline..., the trendline that I get is y = 0.5425x + 12.205

When I run the same data set through the Data Analysis Toolpak (Regression), I get a trendline of y=1.65333 - 17.26667

Aren't these two things supposed to be the same, except perhaps for rounding? What are some common causes of this issue? I've already checked to make sure all of my data values are included in both.

Edit: here is the data set (y is the first column, x is the second; can't get this to format properly in stackoverflow)

y: 3, 4, 8, 7, 15, 25, 35, 45, 60, 80

x: 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50

Edit (update): I verified by hand, and the results of the Data Analysis Toolpak are correct; the trendline on the scatter plot is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

I found the source of the error: the Data Analysis Toolpak understood that I had the columns ordered (y, x) (i.e., y was in column A and x was in column B); however, the scatter plot did not. So the scatter plot was doing x vs y instead of y vs x.